# Does "set at rest" mean "resolve,satisfy"?

Tags: meaning

Does "set at rest" mean "resolve,satisfy"?

*If he had any doubts that raps were independent of
the medium they were (author and the medium) finally satisfied that raps are independent of the medium in that occasion? am i right?*

The author has come to the
conclusion, as already stated, that up to a point they are under the
control of the medium, and that beyond that point they are not. He
cannot easily forget the distress and embarrassment of a great Northcountry
medium when in the author's presence loud raps, sounding like
the snapping of fingers, broke out round his head in the coffee-room of
a Doncaster hotel. If he had any doubts that raps were independent of
the medium they were finally **set at rest upon** that occasion.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/set+at+rest

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109542/discussion-on-question-by-princess-does-set-at-rest-mean-resolve-satisfy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never heard "set at rest" used. It seems to me like someone has mixed up the phrase "*put* to rest" and the word "settled", both of which can mean "resolved". "Put to rest" (or sometimes "lay to rest") is particularly idiomatic when talking about *doubts* as in your example.

"Upon" is a little more formal than "on", and it seems out of place in this sentence.

A more natural way to say this would be:

> If he had any doubts that raps were independent of the medium they were finally **put to rest on** that occasion.